# Probability exercise

Tags: probability

A couple has $3$ kids, and $1$ of them is known to be male.

What is the probability that $1$ (only $1$) of the other $2$ kids is male?

Comment: Try writing out a list of all the possible combinations of males and females. Although the answer does depend on how it is known one of them is male. If one of the 3 kids is picked randomly, and is male, that's different.

Comment: I'm not sure how to consider the knowledge of "already" having a male. Seems to me that the answer is 1/2, because the events on the "other" $2$ kids is independent from the event of "already" having $1$ male. Is that right?

Comment: If we know which of the 3 is male, then there are 4 possible configurations for the remaining 2, in which case 2 of the 4 possible configurations meet our requirements (only one other male). If, however, we only know that one child is male (but do not know which one) there are 7 possible configurations, of which 3 of them are valid.

Comment: I agree with your answer. But I think the solution is $1/2$ because the question says the "other $2$", meaning that we just focus on them $2$.

PS: I found this question in a book, so I'm just reporting it as it is formulated.

Comment: @Adam  you are correct,because  from two child,each one is independent to each other,probability is $1/2=0.5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in generally,if we consider $3$ child,and we know that only $1$ is  male,then probability of being  any choosen child  male is $1/3$,but if our  space is consisted by two child then possibility of all  combination is,let choose  male as $M$,and female $F$,so
$(F,F)$,$(F,M)$,$(M,F)$,$(M,M)$  probability is  $2/4=1/2$

Answer (score 4):

I'll give the answer for a slightly easier variation and let you work out the rest for yourself.

*Question : A family has two kids, at least one of which is a boy. What is the probability that the other kid is also a boy ?*

Let *A* be the event "at least one of the kids is a boy" and *B* the event "both kids are boys". We want to know the *conditional* probability $P_A(B)$, so we write 
$$P_A(B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(B)}{P(A)} = \frac{\tfrac{1}{4}}{\tfrac{3}{4}} = \frac{1}{3}$$

A similar reasoning gives the answer you're looking for : $\frac{3}{7}$ (**not $\frac{1}{2}$**).

**Edit**

There seems to be quite a lot of confusion on this issue, so I'll give more details.

We consider a family of three kids, and we make the (reasonable) assumptions that each kid has a probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of being male, independently of all the others.
The question (rephrased for clarification) is "*If we know that there is at least one boy in a family, what is the probability that there are exactly two boys in that family?*".

The important thing to understand is that this is a **conditional probability**. More precisely, we want to calculate $P(B|A)$, where

- $A$ : "there is at least one boy in the family"
- $B$ : "there are exactly two boys in the family"

The formula for $P(A|B)$ is $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$. Here, we have $P(A \cap B) = P(B)$ (if there are two boys in the family, there is necessarily *at least one* boy). Thus, we simply need the values of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

If we know what random variables are, we can simply observe that the number of boys in the family follows a binomial distribution $\mathcal{B}(3,\frac{1}{2})$, but this is not really needed. We can simply list all the possible outcomes of the experiment and count how many of these outcomes correspond to our events. In order to do that, we need to ensure that all the outcomes we define have *the same probability*. This will be the case if we define our outcomes to be *tuples* (ordered lists) of the sexes of the children. We then have 8 outcomes : 
$$\Omega = \{(M,M,M),(M,M,F),(M,F,M),(M,F,F),(F,M,M),(F,M,F),(F,F,M),(F,F,F)\}$$
7 of these outcomes correspond to $A$ (all but the last one), 3 correspond to $B$.

So we get $P(A)=\frac{7}{8}$, $P(B)=\frac{3}{8}$ and $\boxed{P(B|A)= \frac{\tfrac{3}{8}}{\tfrac{7}{8}}=\frac{3}{7}}$, which is the desired answer.

Alternatively, we could say that there are only seven possible outcomes 
$$\Omega' = \{(M,M,M),(M,M,F),(M,F,M),(M,F,F),(F,M,M),(F,M,F),(F,F,M)\}$$
each of which has probability $\frac{1}{7}$ and three of which correspond to the event $B$. We get the same answer, this time by changing our universe (instead of using the usual technique of keeping the same universe and using conditional probabilities).

**EDIT** : last update, I'm only supposed to teach this during the school year :) This is an answer to a comment below by @Adam which I could not fit in a comment.

The first thing to understand is that the number of possible outcomes is *not important*. Actually, different (but equally valid) ways to model your situation will give you different universes and different numbers of possible outcomes. That is not a problem because the probabilities of these outcomes will also be different so you will get the same probability for all your events in the end (assuming your models are both valid, obviously).

Second thing : if the question was "a family has two kids, their first-born is a boy, what is the probability that the other is a boy ?", the answer would be $\frac{1}{2}$. So the whole thing depends on how we interpret the "one of which is known to be male" in your original question (which is extremely ambiguous, almost certainly in purpose). A few things to think about :

- you meet a man, he tells you he has two siblings. What is the probability that he has exactly one brother ? Answer : $\frac{1}{2}$.
- you meet a man, he tells you he has three kids. You ask him whether they're all girls, he answers no. What is the probability that he has exactly two sons ? Answer : $\frac{3}{7}$

If you understand the reasoning behind these answers, then you have understood whatever it was that exercise was supposed to teach you.

Comment: i have question .if we know that  at least  one of them is boy.we know  that  for second  child,possibility is boy or girl,because second child does not depend on first one,it means that both have equaly likely possibility or $1/2$

Comment: @dato Actually, it's quite tricky : if we know that the eldest is a boy (for instance), then the probability that the youngest is a boy is $\frac{1}{5}$. If we know that at least one is a boy, the probability that the other is a boy is only $\frac{1}{3}$. Basically, if you know that at least one is a boy, your universe is $\{(M,F),(F,M),(M,M)\}$ (and the probability is uniform). Exactly one of those three possibilities corresponds to the event "the other is a boy", so the answer is indeed $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: but look for this  example,we dont need write   $(M,F)$ twice yes?they are same

Comment: No they're not ! If you consider the outcomes of two flips of a (balanced) coin and you are only interested in the number of "heads" you get, you can use $\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,T)\}$ as your universe, but in that case you *do not* have equiprobability : the outcome $(H,T)$ is twice as likely as $(T,T)$.

Comment: All the results given assume that the probability of a boy birth is 1/2 and also that the probability for a second child is independent of the first.  While the probability of a boy birth is close to 1/2 I think statistical studies have shown that it is slightly greater than 1/2.  More importantly individual couples may not have equal probabilities.  Consider families with 10 children (all boys) oe (all girls).  Such result can happen by chance on rare occasions but it is also possible that there is some characteristic in the male sperm or the females acidity level in the vagina affecting it.

Comment: Anyway my point is that these assumptions are not so obviously true and should be mentioned in defining the problem.

Comment: I'm not very clear about your answer. I mean the event "at least one of the kids is a boy" has probability $1$ (not $3/4$) because we already know that $1$ kid is a boy.

Comment: In the simplified example (with two kids), the possible outcomes (*a priori*) are $\{(F,F),(F,M),(M,F),(M,M)\}$, each with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. As you know that there is at least one boy, you're left with 3 possible outcomes, which still all have the same probability. However, that probability is now $\frac{1}{3}$, and as only one of the outcomes corresonds to "the other kid is a boy", that event has probability $\frac{1}{3}$. Try to do the same for your original problem.

Comment: Still not clear. Even for the simplified problem, there are only 2 possible outcomes since we already know about 1 kid. So the probability should be 1/2. Think about flipping a coin after the knowledge you got an head in the previous launch. You still get 1/2.

Comment: I agree with your rephrased question, but not with the original one.